# help needed with json_encode($array) problem please

Tags: jquery, json

i have this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
            alert(json);  //as a test for now
        });
    }
</script>
```

then i have my getMessageDetails.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('header_application.php');
$lastNewMessageCnt = $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']) + 1;
$last_unopened_message_row = $obj_clean->getLastUnopenedMessage($_SESSION['user_id'],$lastNewMessageCnt); 

echo json_encode($last_unopened_message_row);
```

?>

and my html:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><a id = "message_id" class="red_link" href="'.ADDRESS.'view_message.php?id='.$r['id'].'"><span id = "subject">'.$r['subject'].'</span></a></td>';
echo '<td id = "unique_code1">'.$uniqueCode1.'<span id = "unique_code2" class="pink_text">'.$uniqueCode2.'</span><span id = "unique_code3">'.$uniqueCode3.'</span></td>';
echo "</tr>";
```

how come when i alert(json) i get the values im supposed to get which is the last message:

```
[{"subject":"Freechat ha ha","id":"15","created_at":"2011-08-29 11:16:45","unique_code":"LUCINEM000RC","opened_once":"0"}]
```

BUT as soon as i code this:

```
alert($("#subject").html(json.subject));  
alert($("#message_id").html(json.id));
alert($("#unique_code1").html(json.unique_code));
```

i get the first message's details??? which is not what i want
where am i going wrong please??
thank you

Comment: Why bother with the ugly `alert`? There is the shiny beautiful `console.log` now. What are you trying to do? You can't access the JSON object like that, because it's wrapped inside an array, you would have to do `json[0].subject`, ...

Comment: yikes ooooh... i must just refresh/update the page with all new messages as they come in... i did non know of console.log...wil try it, thank you... what is supposed to happen with console.log??? tried it and nothing is displayed??

Comment: comment `header()` in `getMessageDetails.php`  and directly open this file in browser and see what errors are coming??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

- object are denoted by `{}`
- array are denoted by `[]`

so to access the requred data, you need to do so..

```
alert(json[0].subject);
alert('<br>'+json[0].id);
alert('<br>'+json[0].created_at);
alert('<br>'+json[0].unique_code);
alert('<br>'+json[0].opened_once);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MYEug/)

### UPDATE

actually there is problem in ur jquery function

either use **[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)**

or if you are using [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) then write `"json"` as an third argument  like this

```
function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {               
        },"json"); // <---here
    }
```

NOTE: why don't you install firebug, that will tell your error runtime

Comment: thank you i have it like this now but get all of them undefined???

alert(json) gives:
[{"subject":"Freechat bbb","id":"17","created_at":"2011-08-29 11:31:36","unique_code":"LUCINEM000RC","opened_once":"0"}]

Comment: comment `header()` in `getMessageDetails.php:` and then try again

Comment: thank you but: 

1. commented out the header() line
2. added "json" as 3rd argument still get undefined

Comment: i am working in chrome and if i right click on the page, go down to inspect element..i get similar thing as to firebug :) also: i dont get errors i get the alert as undefind :)

Comment: coool thanks! i click on the JSON tab and get all the right values
created_at
"2011-08-29 11:31:36"
id
"17"
opened_once
"0"
subject
"Freechat bbb"
unique_code
"LUCINEM000RC"

Comment: clear the cache and try again... u must have some other problems...examine all errors on firebug again. and one more thing; please upvote if it is worthy..Thanks :)

Comment: i cleared the cache..i do not have any errors....there are no indication of any errors under each of the tabs i click on in fire bug   i am very new to this..sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert(json[0].subject);
```

since the json string is wrapped in `[]` it forms an array from which you want to get the first element